# How can I get the below output using pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pyspark

input_df,

```
|  name  |  type   |  description | win_name |  value |
________________________________________________________ 
| sonu   | doctor  |  dentist     |  monu    |   false |   
| monu   | doctor  |   ortho      |  monu    |    true |
| chintu | doctor  |  dentist     |  monu    |   false |
```

In this dataframe if I change the value of sonu as true, the the win_name should be sonu for all, find df below -

```
|  name  |  type   |  description | win_name |  value |
________________________________________________________ 
| sonu   | doctor  |  dentist     |  sonu    |   true  |   
| monu   | doctor  |   ortho      |  sonu    |   false |
| chintu | doctor  |  dentist     |  sonu    |   false |
```

I am just wondering, is there any way to do this with window functions?

Comment: read a good book about pandas, and it will be clear how to solve this homework

Comment: do you have any ordering column? spark does not retain dataframe order due to its distributed nature. so, while processing in spark, "sonu" might not be the first record. in case only 1 row can have `True`, then you could just filter and join the row.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible way you could try using:

### 1. Importing necessary packages and creating a Spark session

```py
# == Necessary Imports =========================================================
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as funcs
import pyspark.pandas as ps


# == Retrieve or Create Spark Session ==========================================
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

### 2. Create dummy test DataFrame

```py
# == Create Dummy DataFrame ====================================================
df = ps.DataFrame(
    [
        ["sonu", "doctor", "dentist", "monu", False],
        ["monu", "doctor", "ortho", "monu", True],
        ["chintu", "doctor", "dentist", "monu", False],
    ], columns=["name", "type", "description", "win_name", "value"]
).to_spark()
```

### 3. Solution

```py
# == Solution ==================================================================
# First let's create a temporary column called "win_name2".
# This column will be populated using the following conditions:
# 1. If there's a "name" == "sonu", and its "value" is set to True, then populate
#    this row with the name "sonu".
# 2. If there's a "name" == "sonu", and its "value" is set to False, then populate
#    this row with the values from column "win_name"
# 3. Otherwise, populate row with None.
df = df.withColumn(
    "win_name2",
    funcs.when(
        (funcs.col("name") == "sonu") & (funcs.col("value") == True), funcs.lit("sonu")
    ).otherwise(
        funcs.when(
            (funcs.col("name") == "sonu") & (funcs.col("value") == False), funcs.col("win_name")
        ).otherwise(None)
    )
)
# Assuming there can't be a row with "name" equal to "sonu" and "value" set to False
# alongside another row with "name" "sone" and "value" set to True, the created
# column "win_name2" will either have a value of "sonu" and missing values (None),
# or it will have the same values as the original column "win_name2".
# Therefore, in case "win_name2" contains the value "sony" and a bunch of missing
# values, we can apply a `fillna` transformation, filling the missing values with
# the only non-missing value that exists, or in case the "win_name2" column got
# populated with values from "win_name", the fillna won't change anything and keep
# the original values unchanged.
#
# When "name" == "sonu" and "value" == True, we get the following values:
# +------+------+-----------+--------+-----+---------+
# |  name|  type|description|win_name|value|win_name2|
# +------+------+-----------+--------+-----+---------+
# |  sonu|doctor|    dentist|    monu| true|     sonu|  <--
# |  monu|doctor|      ortho|    monu| true|     null|
# |chintu|doctor|    dentist|    monu|false|     null|
# +------+------+-----------+--------+-----+---------+
#
# When "name" == "sonu" and "value" == False, we get the following values:
# +------+------+-----------+--------+-----+
# |  name|  type|description|win_name|value|
# +------+------+-----------+--------+-----+
# |  sonu|doctor|    dentist|    monu|false|
# |  monu|doctor|      ortho|    monu| true|
# |chintu|doctor|    dentist|    monu|false|
# +------+------+-----------+--------+-----+
df = df.fillna(list(df.select(funcs.mode("win_name2")).collect()[0].asDict().values())[0], subset="win_name2")

# Finally, we can replace the column "win_name" with the values from "win_name2",
# and drop the temporary column "win_name2" we created.
df = df.withColumn("win_name", funcs.col("win_name2")).drop("win_name2")
df.show()
```

## Using Pandas-on-Spark

Newer versions of `PySpark` implement a `pandas` API that runs internally on Spark RDDs. Manipulating and transforming your data using the `pandas` API is easier, than the above solution, while still enabling you to take advantage of Spark's parallel computing capabilities. You can convert data from `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` to `pyspark.pandas.frame.DataFrame` using the following method: `.to_pandas_on_spark()`. To convert it back to `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` afterwards, you can use the method `.to_spark()`. Here's how to solve your problem using `pandas-on-spark`:

```py
df = df.to_pandas_on_spark()

if ((df["name"] == "sonu") & (df["value"] == True)).any():
    df["win_name"] = "sonu"

df.to_spark().show()
# Returns:
#
# +------+------+-----------+--------+-----+
# |  name|  type|description|win_name|value|
# +------+------+-----------+--------+-----+
# |  sonu|doctor|    dentist|    sonu| true|
# |  monu|doctor|      ortho|    sonu| true|
# |chintu|doctor|    dentist|    sonu|false|
# +------+------+-----------+--------+-----+
```